# pplawait.h / experimental/resumable for co_await doesn't work

Tags: c++, async-await, visual-studio-2017, coroutine, c++20

I have installed on windows 10.0 visual studio 2017 (version 15.2)
I have migrating from VS2013 to VS2017 for my project (that include cpprestsdk) and change .then() method with co_await. I have read something on the web but actually i can't compile my solution anymore.
Cannot open include file pplawait.h 
ignoring unknown opion '/await'

Suggestions?

Comment: I solved changing Built Version in C/C++ proprierties from v120 to v141

Answer (score 1):

Using coroutines with Visual Studio 2017 and an MFC solution into which I am using C++/WinRT with its `async` type functions, I have the following.

See as well this question and my answer which contains several examples of using coroutines with `concurrency`, `std:async` and C++/WinRT: [C++11 threads to update MFC application windows. SendMessage(), PostMessage() required?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50669108/c11-threads-to-update-mfc-application-windows-sendmessage-postmessage-re)

First of all settings in the solution Properties.

- Configuration Properties -> General -> Platform Toolset Visual Studio 2017 (v141)
- C/C++ -> All Options -> Additional Options -> /await
- C/C++ -> All Options -> C++ Language Standard ISO C++17 Standard (/stdc++17)

[image: settings for Properties - Configuration Properties]

[image: settings for Properties - C/C++ (compiler settings)]

And the source code for the actual function that I am using (C++/WinRT async function with `co_await`):

```
#include <pplawait.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")
#include "winrt/Windows.Foundation.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Web.Syndication.h"

// . . .  other code

// sample function using co_await to retrieve an RSS feed which may take
// a while so we want to start it and then continue when the results are
// received. we are using one of the async functions of C++/WinRT to retrieve
// the RSS feed text. We require a pointer to a CMainFrame object which has
// the function we need to output the text lines to a displayed window.
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction myTaskMain(CMainFrame *p)
{
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::Uri uri(L"http://kennykerr.ca/feed");
    winrt::Windows::Web::Syndication::SyndicationClient client;
    winrt::Windows::Web::Syndication::SyndicationFeed feed = co_await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri);

    // send the text strings of the RSS feed list to an MFC output window for
    // display to the user.
    for (winrt::Windows::Web::Syndication::SyndicationItem item : feed.Items())
    {
        winrt::hstring title = item.Title().Text();
        p->SendMessageToOutputWnd(WM_APP, COutputWnd::OutputBuild, (LPARAM)title.c_str());  // print a string to an output window in the output pane.
    }
}
```