# C++11 threads to update MFC application windows. SendMessage(), PostMessage() required?

Tags: multithreading, c++11, mfc, visual-studio-2017, c++-winrt

After spending a bit of time with simple UWP applications with C++/CX and ++/WinRT I have begun to enjoy some of the features of targeting that environment for Windows UI app development.

Now having to go back to a more familiar MFC application development I want to change my approach to something that is similar to UWP app development. The idea is to use asynchronous C++11 threads to generate content and modify content that is displayed in the MFC UI.

The main change I want to make is to use C++11 threads to offload some time-consuming tasks and have those threads communicate the results back to the main MFC UI.

Some of the tasks that I am looking to offload onto C++11 threads, which are similar to what I would use with asynchronous tasks with C++/CX and C++/WinRT in UWP apps are:

- connect to and exchange data with another computer
- open a data file and parse it to update the UI view
- convert a data file to another format such as CSV and export to a file
- read a file in a format such as CSV and convert the content into a data file
- perform searches and filtering of the presentation of the data file in the UI

The problem I am running into is similar to the problem described in [Can I have multiple GUI threads in MFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17340285/can-i-have-multiple-gui-threads-in-mfc), however, I am looking for a general approach rather than the specific progress bar update in that question.

I have been trying a simple test with an experimental MFC app using the Visual Studio template which has a tree control docked on the left to build the tree in a worker thread.

If I have a `CViewTree`, an MFC window that displays a tree view, which I want to update from a C++11 thread, I am currently using `::PostMessage()` to request that the tree control in the docked pane is updated.

If I use a lambda with a global `std::thread` such as the following code:

```
std::thread t1;

void CClassView::FillClassView()
{
    // ::SendMessage() seems to deadlock so ::PostMessage() is required.
    t1 = std::thread([this]() { Sleep(5000);  ::PostMessage(this->m_hWnd, WM_COMMAND, ID_NEW_FOLDER, 0); });

}
```

the message handler for the MFC docked pane which looks like:

```
void CClassView::OnNewFolder()
{
    t1.join();   // this join seems to deadlock if ::SendMessage() is used.

    AddItemsToPane(m_wndClassView);
}
```

does indeed update the MFC docked pane with the tree control content just as if the function `AddItemsToPane(m_wndClassView);` were called at the same place where the C++11 thread is created. The pane update is delayed by 5 seconds when the C++11 thread is used just to provide a visible indication that the thread approach is actually working.

My problem is that I want the C++11 thread to create the content for the tree control and provide it to the docked pane rather than having the docked pane generate the content.

Thus far the only approach I can think of is to develop my own class library that will provide C++11 thread analogues to the MFC library and controls using `::PostMessage()` to send the appropriate Windows messages to the designated MFC window or control.

I am wondering if it is possible to have the C++11 threads have their own, shadowing MFC control which they update and then send a message to the UI asking the UI to update its displayed control with the contents of the shadow MFC control? Or is there some other approach that people are using?

I am looking for some other, less arduous approaches to solving this problem of updating an MFC UI from C++11 threads.

**By the way #1** `::SendMessage()` appears to deadlock on the `join()` in `CClassView::OnNewFolder()` which I assume means that some kind of synchronization between the C+11 thread and the UI thread is blocking the C++11 thread from reaching its side of the `join()`?

Yes there is a deadlock as the thread waits for `SendMessage()` to return while the message handler is waiting at the `join()` for the thread to finish. According to the [Windows Dev Center SendMessage function](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644950(v=vs.85).aspx):

> Sends the specified message to a window or windows. The `SendMessage`
>   function calls the window procedure for the specified window and **does
>   not return until the window procedure has processed the message**.
>
> To send a message and return immediately, use the `SendMessageCallback`
>   or `SendNotifyMessage` function. To post a message to a thread's message
>   queue and return immediately, use the `PostMessage` or `PostThreadMessage`
>   function.

**By the way #2** It would also seem that using the actual Window handle rather than the `this` pointer in the lambda for the C++11 thread would be safer. Just in case the `this` pointer becomes undefined for some reason such as the control is removed?

**By the way #3** The Microsoft `concurrency` namespace, provided via `#include <ppltasks.h>`, is an alternative to C++11 threads. The `concurrency` namespace functions are at a higher level of abstraction than C++11 threads and are easier to use.

For instance the above use of `std:thread` could be rewritten as:

```
void CClassView::FillClassView()
{
    concurrency::create_task([this]() { Sleep(5000);  ::SendMessage(this->m_hWnd, WM_COMMAND, ID_NEW_FOLDER, 0); });
}
```

and this does not require the use of a `std::thread join()` to cleanly terminate the thread. Also `SendMessage()` or `PostMessage()` may be used to send the Windows message since we do not have the same deadlock issue as we have with C++11 threads.

**Notes**

*Note #1:* [About Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644927(v=vs.85).aspx) as well as [Using Messages and Message Queues](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms644928(v=vs.85).aspx).

For MFC specific content see [Messages and Commands in the Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/70sw24a7.aspx).

*Note #2:* [Multithreading with C++ and MFC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/975t8ks0.aspx) and specifically [Multithreading: Programming Tips](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h14y172e.aspx) which says.

> If you have a multithreaded application that creates a thread in a way
>   other than using a CWinThread object, you cannot access other MFC
>   objects from that thread. In other words, if you want to access any
>   MFC object from a secondary thread, you must create that thread with
>   one of the methods described in Multithreading: Creating
>   User-Interface Threads or Multithreading: Creating Worker Threads.
>   These methods are the only ones that allow the class library to
>   initialize the internal variables necessary to handle multithreaded
>   applications.

*Note #3:* [UWP APIs callable from a classic desktop app](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/mt695951(v=vs.85).aspx) which says:

> With some notable exceptions, the general rule is that a Universal
>   Windows Platform (UWP) API can be called from a classic desktop app.
>   The two main areas of APIs that are an exception to this general rule
>   are XAML UI APIs, and APIs that require the calling app to have a
>   package identity. UWP apps have a well-defined app model, and they
>   have a package identity. Classic desktop apps do not have a
>   well-defined app model, and they do not have a package identity. A
>   classic desktop app that has been converted to a UWP app does have a
>   package identity.

See as well the following blogs from Sep 2012 about WinRT with VS 2012 and Windows 8. Though C++/WinRT with VS 2017 seems more appropriate for Windows 10 than Windows Runtime template Library (WRL) used:

- [Accessing WinRT From Desktop apps (Part 1)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/13/accessing-winrt-from-desktop-apps-part-1/)
- [Accessing WinRT from Desktop Apps (Part 2)](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/24/accessing-winrt-from-desktop-apps-part-2/)

*Note #4:* [MFC Desktop Applications](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d06h2x6e.aspx) which is a jumping off point with lots of links. See also [MFC COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k851ext3.aspx) which is a jumping off point with lots of links about MFC with COM along with this article [Introduction to COM](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bwa2bx93.aspx). See as well [MFC Macros and Globals](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f2dch7fb.aspx).

As for using `AfxGetMainWnd()` to get the main application window, the Microsoft developer center has this to say in the article [AfxGetMainWnd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/waas15s1.aspx):

> If AfxGetMainWnd is called from the application's primary thread, it
>   returns the application's main window according to the above rules. If
>   the function is called from a secondary thread in the application, the
>   function returns the main window associated with the thread that made
>   the call.

Comment: So, why **aren't** you using C++/WinRT, or C++20 coroutines? This sounds like you are trying to implement, what's already there. C++/WinRT has facilities that allow you to continue running code on any particular thread (like your GUI thread), from any given coroutine.

Comment: @IInspectable I am working on spinning up with C++/WinRT however it appears that it requires Windows 10 unless I am missing something. I have a project to do quickly so the time for learning the quite extensive C++/WinRT perspective and toolkit seems daunting at the moment. I have materials that I can reuse by taking an MFC approach allowing me to cut down on development effort. Going from old resource file to XAML looks effortful. I don't want to reinvent the C++/WinRT wheel in MFC but do want to use some of those lessons. Any advice?

Comment: @IInspectable what I am considering now is to use a more traditional, synchronous MFC approach for most things and to use the C++11 threads for specific, non-UI related behavior and tasks. Better half a cup than failing with an attempt at a full cup. Most of what I need to do would work fine by not being too ambitious.

Comment: I think you just have a long import/export function which freezes the window, this would be relatively easy to solve. One GUI thread is enough. This can have multiple mode-less windows. You can add worker threads which communicate with GUI. `std::thread(foo).join()` will block the parent GUI. Use `AfxBeginThread` if possible. `SendMessage` waits for completion, `PostMessage` returns immediately.

Comment: _"threads have their own, shadowing MFC control which they update"_ -- doesn't sound like good encapsulation. Worker thread should not be bothered about specifics of GUI. It should communicate the results to UI, but not be coupled to specific UI controls. Question is too broad.

Comment: Asynchronous tasks in C++/WinRT are implemented as coroutines. You can use coroutines in MFC; they are supported starting with Visual Studio 2017. I wasn't suggesting to port your entire application to a XAML UI either. I was suggesting to use the C++/WinRT coroutine helpers (e.g. `resume_background`).

Comment: @BarmakShemirani I don't see why `AfxBeginThread` should be preferred. One can use `std::thread::join()` in UI thread, when the UI thread already knows that the thread is about to end (e. g. when receiving a "finished" notification from the thread via `PostMessage()`). Another way is to run your own message loop using `MsgWaitForMultipleObjectsEx()`, passing `std::thread::native_handle()` handle.

Comment: @IInspectable I was originally under the impression that C++/WinRT was an all or nothing proposition. I spent some time last night doing additional reading and began questioning that impression. Much of C++/WinRT seems to be COM under the hood. Was looking at `concurrency` namespace and coroutines, was going to start experimenting. Seems to be several, converging technologies C++11, C++17, C++20, Microsoft specific. Are you suggesting `concurrency` namespace?

Comment: @zett42 from what I have read, `AfxBeginThread` is also always a heavy, OS thread which may not be appropriate, not really similar to thread pools of C++/WinRT. `std::thread` may be similar to `AfxBeginThread` in startup costs. Was looking at `std::async` as well and am coming to conclusion that C++/WinRT does the "asynchronous task" thing better than standard C++.

Comment: UWP is based on the Windows Runtime, a type system based on COM. The majority of the API surface is available to any program, namely those with the `DualApiPartitionAttribute`. C++/WinRT as a header-only library can be dropped into just about any project. There is documentation in the MSDN on [Concurrency and asynchronous operations with C++/WinRT](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency), that showcases how to use coroutines. You'll have to use the [/await](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/await-enable-coroutine-support) compiler option.

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the reference to `DualApiPartitionAttribute` and I have added Note #3 and Note #4 with a link to a brief article about it. I assume any MFC source using C++/WinRT will need to be COM aware using `OleInitialize()`? Or perhaps ` AfxOleInit()` with MFC?

Comment: @zett42 `std::thread::join` stops the message loop. Your solution about creating a different message loop is not trivial, and even less portable. Anyway, I think that's going off-topic.

Comment: Have you thought of just using a `CWinThread` derived object? It works so well with MFC. And you can post messages back and forth all day long between the thread object and your main thread. I use one that runs the whole time the app is alive to spell check and thesaurus several windows concurrently. It works great..

Comment: @lakeweb I have used `CWinThread` before. I was hoping to move into C++11/17 by using C++ standard collections and functionality as much as possible and MFC other than the window framework as little as possible. So the idea was to not use `CWinThread`, `CString`, etc. see this discussion though it is from 2009 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348078/why-stl-containers-are-preferred-over-mfc-containers and I seem to remember a recommendation some time back in a Microsoft article to prefer STL to MFC in new code.

Comment: Hi Richard, yes. I would agree and at that point use boost. But if like me, you are going to use MFC, why not just use what is comparable? But then if your UI is lite on the MFC side... Anytime I'm looking to be independent, it is also of the windows platform. That is why boost. About as cross platform as it gets. I've used [Boost Asio](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_66_0/doc/html/boost_asio.html) with MFC, that worked out great.

Comment: To initialize the Windows Runtime on the calling thread, call [RoInitialize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/br224650.aspx).

Comment: @IInspectable thanks for the info re `RoInitialize()`. Thus far I found these two short blog posts from Sep 2012 about "Accessing WinRT from Desktop apps", http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/13/accessing-winrt-from-desktop-apps-part-1/ and http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/pavely/2012/09/24/accessing-winrt-from-desktop-apps-part-2/ and there is this post that provides some details which may be too low level actually https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/23473.implementing-a-complete-wrl-native-c-xaml-blank-project-template.aspx

Comment: Those articles are still valid, although they were published at a time, when there was only C++/CX and C++ (without a proper projection). Even while using the [WRL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/windows/windows-runtime-cpp-template-library-wrl), code was still very verbose. C++/WinRT provides a true projection, which is intended to replace C++/CX. While you can use Windows Runtime types, I was suggesting C++/WinRT for the sole reason of being the only official first-party library, that provides helpers to control the thread of execution for a coroutine.

Comment: @IInspectable I have provided an attempt at an answer. Could you take a look and let me know where I went wrong or left something important out? I am thinking I may do some additional experimentation and then put the results up in GitHub along with a linkage between the repository and this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some experimentation, there are a few recommendations that I feel comfortable making.

- the `concurrency` task functionality is easier to use than C++11 `std:thread` and is more flexible in using with coroutines however `std::async` is easier to use than `std::thread` and works with `co_await` as well
- coroutines using `co_await` look to be a great addition with `concurrency` when using C++/WinRT and the `Async` type functions in WinRT (see [C++ Coroutines: Understanding operator co_await](https://lewissbaker.github.io/2017/11/17/understanding-operator-co-await) for a technical explanation)
- you can make your own async functions using the `concurrency::task<>` template as the return type of the function or use `concurrency::create_task()` and you can use `co_await` with such a task
- you can also use `co_await` with `std::async()` since `std::async()` returns a `std::future<>` which has an Awaitable interface (see [await/yield: C++ coroutines](http://cpp.mimuw.edu.pl/files/await-yield-c++-coroutines.pdf) though it is dated Nov-2016)
- you can also use `co_await` with a `std::future<>` as provided by the `get_future()` method of a `std::packaged_task<>` ( see also [What is the difference between packaged_task and async](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18143661/what-is-the-difference-between-packaged-task-and-async) )
- you can make generator functions using `std::experimental::generator<type>` as a function return type along with the `co_yield` operator to return a value of the specified type in the generated series
- to update the MFC UI requires that any code runs in the MFC UI thread the MFC object was created so Windows messages are needed to communicate with the MFC windows and window class objects from other threads or you must switch the thread context/affinity to the UI thread context for that object
- `winrt::apartment_context` can be used to capture the current thread context and later resumed using `co_await` which may be used to capture the main UI thread context to be reused later (see [Programming with thread affinity in mind](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency#programming-with-thread-affinity-in-mind) in the article Concurrency and asynchronous operations with C++/WinRT)
- `co_await winrt::resume_background();` can be used to push the current thread's context to a background thread which can be useful for a lengthy task that may be in the main UI thread context and you want to make sure that it is not
- when sending messages to a window, make sure that the window actually has been created and exists, during application startup the application must create windows before you can use them; *just because the MFC class exists does not mean the underlying window has been created yet*
- `::SendMessage()` is synchronous in which the message is sent and a response is returned
- `::PostMessage()` is asynchronous in which the message is sent and a response is not returned
- using `::PostMessage()` be careful that pointers sent in messages do not go out of scope before the receiver uses them as there is typically a delay between when `::PostMessage()` returns and the message handle receiving the message actually does something with the message
- probably the most straightforward approach is to use the `ON_MESSAGE()` macro in the message map with a message handler interface of `afx_msg LRESULT OnMessageThing(WPARAM, LPARAM)`
- you can use Windows message identifiers in the space beginning with the defined constant of `WM_APP` and the same identifier can be used in different classes
- you can use much of C++/WinRT quite easily with MFC with just a bit of care though admittedly I only have tried a few things and there are some limitations such as not using XAML according to the documentation
- if you do use C++/WinRT within an MFC application, *you are limiting your application to versions of Windows that has the Windows Runtime* which pretty much means Windows 10 (this rules out using C++/WinRT with Windows 7, POS Ready 7, etc.)
- using C++/WinRT requires adding compiler option `/stdc++17` to enable the ISO C++17 Standard for the C++ Language Standard and using coroutines requires the `/await` compiler option

Here are a view resources.

> Microsoft Build 2018
>   [Effective C++/WinRT for UWP and Win32](https://channel9.msdn.com/events/Build/2018/BRK2425?term=uwp%20C%20%20&lang-en=true)
>   May 06, 2018 at 3:27PM by Brent Rector, Kenny Kerr
>
> CppCon 2017: Scott Jones & Kenny Kerr
>   [C++/WinRT and the Future of C++ on Windows](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7TdpWB_vRZM)
>   Published on Nov 2, 2017

Using Visual Studio 2017 Community edition, I created a new MFC Single Document Interface (SDI) project using the Visual Studio style. After the application comes up, it looks like the following image.

[image: screen shot of MFC app in Visual Studio theme]

**Helper functions for messages**

The first change I made was to provide a way to send a Windows message to one of the panes (ClassView or OutputWindow) that I would like to update. Since the `CMainFrame` class in MainFrm.h had the MFC objects for these windows as in:

```
protected:  // control bar embedded members
    CMFCMenuBar       m_wndMenuBar;
    CMFCToolBar       m_wndToolBar;
    CMFCStatusBar     m_wndStatusBar;
    CMFCToolBarImages m_UserImages;
    CFileView         m_wndFileView;
    CClassView        m_wndClassView;
    COutputWnd        m_wndOutput;
    CPropertiesWnd    m_wndProperties;
```

I modified the class to provide a way to send a message to these windows. I chose to use `SendMessage()` rather than `PostMessage()` to eliminate the pointer going out of scope issue. The `concurrency` class works fine with `SendMessage()`.

```
LRESULT  SendMessageToFileView(UINT msgId, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { return m_wndFileView.SendMessage(msgId, wParam, lParam); }
LRESULT  SendMessageToClassView(UINT msgId, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { return m_wndClassView.SendMessage(msgId, wParam, lParam); }
LRESULT  SendMessageToOutputWnd(UINT msgId, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) { return m_wndOutput.SendMessage(msgId, wParam, lParam); }
```

These are the raw, bare infrastructure for sending the messages to update the various MFC windows. I put these into `CMainFrame` class as that is a central point and the `AfxGetMainWnd()` function allows me to access the object of that class at any place within the MFC application. Additional classes to wrap these raw functions would be appropriate.

I then put message handlers into each of the classes within the `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP` and the `END_MESSAGE_MAP` macros. The output window update was the easiest and simplest and look like:

```
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(COutputWnd, CDockablePane)
    ON_WM_CREATE()
    ON_WM_SIZE()
    // ADD_ON: message handler for the WM_APP message containing an index as
    //         to which output window to write to along with a pointer to the
    //         text string to write.
    //         this->SendMessageToOutputWnd(WM_APP, COutputWnd::OutputBuild, (LPARAM)_T("some text"));
    ON_MESSAGE(WM_APP, OnAddItemsToPane)
END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

with the message handler looking like:

```
// ADD_ON: message handler for the WM_APP message containing an array of the
//         struct ItemToInsert above. Uses method AddItemsToPane().
LRESULT  COutputWnd::OnAddItemsToPane(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (wParam) {
    case OutputBuild:
        m_wndOutputBuild.AddString((TCHAR *)lParam);
        break;
    case OutputDebug:
        m_wndOutputDebug.AddString((TCHAR *)lParam);
        break;
    case OutputFind:
        m_wndOutputFind.AddString((TCHAR *)lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I added the method prototype to the class along with this enumeration to make the functionality a bit easier to use.

```
enum WindowList { OutputBuild = 1, OutputDebug = 2, OutputFind = 3 };
```

With the above changes I was able to insert into the message handler for "New" in `BOOL CMFCAppWinRTDoc::OnNewDocument()` the following code to put a text string into the "Build" Output Window:

```
CMainFrame *p = dynamic_cast <CMainFrame *> (AfxGetMainWnd());

if (p) {
    p->SendMessageToOutputWnd(WM_APP, COutputWnd::OutputBuild, (LPARAM)_T("this is a test from OnNewDocument()."));
}
```

**Using C++/WinRT with MFC and `concurrency`**

To test this along with testing using C++/WinRT with MFC, I added the following `concurrency` task to `CMainFrame::OnCreate()` which is called when the application is starting up. This source spins off a task which then uses the `Syndication` functionality of C++/WinRT to fetch an RSS feed list and displays the titles in the OutputWindow pane labeled "Build" as seen in the screen shot above.

```
concurrency::create_task([this]() {
    winrt::init_apartment();

    Sleep(5000);

    winrt::Windows::Foundation::Uri uri(L"http://kennykerr.ca/feed");
    winrt::Windows::Web::Syndication::SyndicationClient client;
    winrt::Windows::Web::Syndication::SyndicationFeed feed = client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri).get();
    for (winrt::Windows::Web::Syndication::SyndicationItem item : feed.Items())
    {
        winrt::hstring title = item.Title().Text();
        this->SendMessageToOutputWnd(WM_APP, COutputWnd::OutputBuild, (LPARAM)title.c_str());  // print a string to an output window in the output pane.
    }
    winrt::uninit_apartment();
});
```

To use the `concurrency` and the C++/WinRT functionality I had to add a couple of include files near the top of MainFrm.c source file.

```
// ADD_ON: include files for using the concurrency namespace.
#include <experimental\resumable>
#include <pplawait.h>

#pragma comment(lib, "windowsapp")
#include "winrt/Windows.Foundation.h"
#include "winrt/Windows.Web.Syndication.h"
```

In addition, I had to modify the Properties of the solution to specify C++17 and an additional compiler option of `/await` which are marked with blue arrows in the screen shot below.
[image: screen shot of Visual Studio solution properties showing changes]

**Using `co_await` with MFC and C++/WinRT**

From a helpful comment from @IInspectable I took a look at coroutines with Visual Studio 2017 and MFC. I have been curious about them however it seemed that I could not come up with anything that would compile without errors from using `co_await`.

However starting with a link in the comment from @IInspectable I found a link to this YouTube video, [CppCon 2016: Kenny Kerr & James McNellis “Putting Coroutines to Work with the Windows Runtime"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v0SjumbIips), which had a source code sample around time 10:28 that finally I was able to come up with something that would compile and work.

I created the following function which I then used to replace the above source with `concurrency::create_task()` and the lambda with a function call to the following function. The function call was simple, `myTaskMain(this);` replacing the `concurrency::create_task([this]() {` lambda in the `int CMainFrame::OnCreate(LPCREATESTRUCT lpCreateStruct)` method and then adding the following source code above the `OnCreate()` function body.

```
winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction myTaskMain(CMainFrame *p)
{
    winrt::Windows::Foundation::Uri uri(L"http://kennykerr.ca/feed");
    winrt::Windows::Web::Syndication::SyndicationClient client;
    winrt::Windows::Web::Syndication::SyndicationFeed feed = co_await client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri);

    Sleep(5000);
    for (winrt::Windows::Web::Syndication::SyndicationItem item : feed.Items())
    {
        winrt::hstring title = item.Title().Text();
        p->SendMessageToOutputWnd(WM_APP, COutputWnd::OutputBuild, (LPARAM)title.c_str());  // print a string to an output window in the output pane.
    }
}
```

There are two changes that I made from the source of the `concurrency::create_task()` being replaced:

- removed the `winrt::init_apartment();` and `winrt::uninit_apartment();` since using them triggered an exception and removing them seems to make no difference
- moved the `Sleep(5000);` to after the `co_await` since leaving it where it was caused the function to sleep for 5 seconds which meant the UI thread slept for 5 seconds

What I found with the debugger was that at the point that the function `myTaskMain()` was called, there was an immediate return from the function and the UI thread continued running while the coroutine executed in the background. The UI displayed promptly and then some five seconds later the additional actions, updating the Class View tree and the RSS feed list in the "Build" tab of the Output Window happened.

*Note #1:* One other thing I have run into with other testing is that the UI will freeze for a few seconds (menu is non-functional). This seems to be due to the `Sleep(5000);` indicating that the code after the `co_await` is being run on the main UI thread. This change in application behavior started after I began to explore using `winrt::apartment_context ui_thread;` to capture the main UI thread context in order to then use `co_await ui_thread;` to return my coroutine thread to the main UI thread context.

What may be happening is that `client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri)` is immediately being satisfied with no delay, perhaps from a cache, so rather than pushing the task to another thread and then returning to the caller, the `co_await` is getting an immediate result back and the function `myTaskMain()` is able to immediately continue using the current thread which is the main UI thread?

I noticed that in Visual Studio 2017 the `co_await` used with `client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri)` is colored green while the `co_await` used with `co_await ui_thread;` is blue. Doing a mouse hover over the green colored `co_await` I get a tool tip indicating this is a different version of `co_await`.

[image: screen shot of mouse hover over green co_await showing operator overload]

*Note #2:* There is a C++/WinRT function to move to a background thread context, `winrt::resume_background()` which can be used with `co_await`. If I modify the above function `myTaskMain()` by replacing the line of code of `Sleep(5000);` after the call to `client.RetrieveFeedAsync(uri)` with the following two lines of code to push the thread context to a background thread, I do not see the freeze (the UI is responsive to menu selections) and the RSS feed text lines are displayed in the "Build" tab of the Output Window after some 15 seconds.

```
co_await winrt::resume_background();  // switch context to background thread

Sleep(15000);
```

**Rolling an async task using `concurrency::task<>` that works with `co_await`**

One thing I was curious about was being able to create my own async task that I could used with `co_await` similar to the async type functions of C++/WinRT. I spent some time searching about until I finally found this article, [Concurrency and asynchronous operations with C++/WinRT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency), with a section called [Asychronously return a non-Windows-Runtime type](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/concurrency#asychronously-return-a-non-windows-runtime-type).

Here is a simple demo function that creates a `concurrency::task<>` with a lambda and returns the task which is then used with `co_await`. This particular lambda is returning an `int` so the function is defined as a task that returns an `int`, `concurrency::task<int>`

```
concurrency::task<int> mySleepTaskAsync()
{
    return concurrency::create_task([]() {
        Sleep(15000);
        return 5;
    });
}
```

The above function is then used with the `co_await` operator in a statement such as:

```
int jj = co_await mySleepTaskAsync();
```

which will cause the variable `jj` to have a value of 5 after a wait of 15 seconds.

The above is used in a function that returns a `winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction` such as the function `myTaskMain()` above.

If you like you can also just directly use the lambda with the `co_await` as in:

```
int jj = co_await concurrency::create_task([]() {
    Sleep(15000);
    return 5;
});
```

Or you could have a normal function such as:

```
int mySleepTaskAsyncInt()
{
        Sleep(15000);
        return 5;
}
```

and then use it with a `co_await` using `concurrency::task<>` as in:

```
int jj = co_await concurrency::create_task(mySleepTaskAsyncInt);
```

**Rolling an async task using `std::async` that works with `co_await`**

While `std::thread` does not work with `co_await`, causing a compilation error, you can use `std::async` with `co_await`. The reason is the kind of return value that `co_await` operator requires and the difference in the return value of `std::thread`, a `std::thread`, and the return value of `std::async`, a `std::future<>`.

The `co_await` operator requires that the variable it is operating on is a `std::future<>`, has a `get()` method to retrieve a result from the thread, and is Awaitable.

```
#include <future>

int mySleepTaskAsyncInt()
{
    Sleep(7000);
    return 5;
}

winrt::Windows::Foundation::IAsyncAction myTaskMain(CMainFrame *p)
{
    auto t1 = co_await std::async (std::launch::async, mySleepTaskAsyncInt);

    // do something with the variable t1
}
```

**Rolling an async task with `std::packaged_task<>` and `std::future<>` with `co_await`**

As the `co_await` requires an Awaitable object, another way to create such an object is to create a task with `std::packaged_task<>` then start the task and use the `get_future()` method of the task to obtain a `std::future<>` which is then usable with `co_await`.

For instance we can have the following simple function that will create a task package, start the task executing, and then return a `std::future<>`. We can then use this function as the target for the `co_await` operator to implement a coroutine.

```
#include <future>


std::future<int> mySleepTaskStdFutureInt()
{
    // create the task to prepare it for running.
    std::packaged_task<int()> task([]() {
        Sleep(7000);
        return 455;   // return an int value
    });

    // start the task running and return the future
    return task(), task.get_future();
}
```

and then in our source code we would use this function similar to:

```
int jkjk = co_await mySleepTaskStdFutureInt();
```

The `return` statement is using the comma operator to introduce a sequence point so that we start the task running and then call the `get_future()` method on the running task. The result of the `get_future()` method, a `std::future<int>` is what is actually returned by the function.

The task that is created with `std::packaged_task()` **must be started** with a function like call using the variable. If you do not start the task then the `std::future<>` returned by the function will never have a variable and the `co_await` that is waiting for the Awaitable to complete and to provide a value will never fire. The result is that the source after your `co_await` will not be executed because the `co_await` will never be triggered.

**Generator with `co_yield` and `std::experimental::generator<type>`**

While investigating `co_await` I came across `co_yield` which is used to return a value as part of a generator of a set of values. With Visual Studio 2017 using `co_yield` requires that the header file `experimental/generator` be included. Here is a simple example of a generator that generates a series of integers.

```
#include <experimental/generator>

std::experimental::generator<int> makeSomeInts(int kCount)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < kCount; i++) {
        co_yield i;
    }
}
```

And this function can be used with a ranged for as in:

```
for (int kkk : makeSomeInts(10)) {
    // code that uses the variable kkk which contains
    // an int from the generated range 0 up to be not including 10.
}
```

The above loop will be executed for each integer value of 0 through and including 9.

**More complex message: updating ClassView pan**

I also did an experiment with the ClassView tree control to provide a simple way of doing the most elementary actions: create an initial tree control and add to it.

In `CClassView` class in the file ClassView.h, I added the following data structs. By the way after I was done, I realized this was probably the wrong place to put this since the `CFileView` class uses the same tree structure so the same approach would work for both of these panes. Anyway, I added the following:

```
// ADD_ON: enumeration listing the various types of tree control icons which
//         correspond to the position of a control in the tree.
// choose either classview_hc.bmp or classview.bmp for the bitmap strip that
// contains the 7 icons we are using for the images in our tree control.
// icons are standard size in height and width (15x15 pixels) in the order of:
//   - main root icon
//   - tree node icon which can be opened to show nodes beneath it
//   - folder icon which is used to indicate a folder
//   - method icon indicating a method of a class
//   - locked method icon
//   - member variable icon
//   - locked member variable icon

enum IconList { MainRoot = 0, TreeNode = 1, FolderNode = 2, MethodNode = 3, MethodLockedNode = 4, MemberNode = 5, MemberLockedNode = 6 };

// ADD_ON: struct used to contain the necessary data for a node in the tree control.
struct ItemToInsert {
    std::wstring  label;            // text to be displayed with the node.
    int           nImage;           // zero based offset of the node's icon in the image, one of enum IconList above.
    int           nSelectedImage;   // zero based offset of the node's icon in the image, one of enum IconList above.
};
```

I created a message handler, and added it to the message map in ClassView.cpp

```
ON_MESSAGE(WM_APP, OnAddItemsToPane)
```

and added the actual message handler itself along with a helper function that does the actual processing.

```
// ADD_ON: function for filling in the ClassView pane using an array of the
//         struct ItemToInsert above. array is terminated by an entry with
//         all zeros as in { _T(""), 0, 0 }
void CClassView::AddItemsToPane(CViewTree &xwndClassView, void *xrayp)
{

    if (xrayp == 0) return;

    // the images are icons that are laid out in a line of icons within a single bitmap image.
    // see class method OnChangeVisualStyle() for when the bitmap image is loaded and then
    // divided up into sections, 0 through 6, of the single bitmap image loaded.
    // see classview.bmp and classview_hc.bmp in the ResourceFiles list.


    HTREEITEM hRoot = xwndClassView.GetRootItem();
    HTREEITEM hClass = 0;
    ItemToInsert *xray = (ItemToInsert *)xrayp;

    for (int i = 0; xray[i].label.size() != 0; i++) {
        switch (xray[i].nImage) {
        case MainRoot:
            hRoot = xwndClassView.InsertItem(xray[i].label.c_str(), xray[i].nImage, xray[i].nSelectedImage);
            xwndClassView.SetItemState(hRoot, TVIS_BOLD, TVIS_BOLD);
            xwndClassView.Expand(hRoot, TVE_EXPAND);
            break;
        case TreeNode:
            hClass = xwndClassView.InsertItem(xray[i].label.c_str(), xray[i].nImage, xray[i].nSelectedImage, hRoot);
            break;
        case FolderNode:
            hClass = xwndClassView.InsertItem(xray[i].label.c_str(), xray[i].nImage, xray[i].nSelectedImage, hRoot);
            break;
        case MethodNode:
        case MethodLockedNode:
        case MemberNode:
        case MemberLockedNode:
            xwndClassView.InsertItem(xray[i].label.c_str(), xray[i].nImage, xray[i].nSelectedImage, hClass);
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
    }
}

// ADD_ON: message handler for the WM_APP message containing an array of the
//         struct ItemToInsert above. Uses method AddItemsToPane().
LRESULT  CClassView::OnAddItemsToPane(WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
{
    switch (wParam) {
    case 1:
        AddItemsToPane(m_wndClassView, (void *)lParam);
        break;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

I then created some sample data for an initial tree and then an add on node.

```
// ADD_ON: this is the content to be put into the ClassView tree pane.
//         this is a tree structure.
CClassView::ItemToInsert xray2[] = {
    { _T("CFakeMainProject"), CClassView::MainRoot, CClassView::MainRoot },
        { _T("CFakeAboutDlg"), CClassView::TreeNode, CClassView::TreeNode },
            { _T("CFakeAboutDlg()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
        { _T("CFakeApp"), CClassView::TreeNode, CClassView::TreeNode },
            { _T("CFakeApp()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
            { _T("InitInstance()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
            { _T("OnAppAbout()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
        { _T("CFakeAppDoc"), CClassView::TreeNode, CClassView::TreeNode },
            { _T("CFakeAppDoc()"), CClassView::MethodLockedNode, CClassView::MethodLockedNode },
            { _T("~CFakeAppDoc()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
            { _T("OnNewDocument()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
        { _T("CFakeAppView"), CClassView::TreeNode, CClassView::TreeNode },
            { _T("CFakeAppView()"), CClassView::MethodLockedNode, CClassView::MethodLockedNode },
            { _T("~CFakeAppView()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
            { _T("GetDocument()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
        { _T("CFakeAppFrame"), CClassView::TreeNode, CClassView::TreeNode },
            { _T("CFakeAppFrame()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
            { _T("~CFakeAppFrame()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
            { _T("m_wndMenuBar"), CClassView::MemberLockedNode, CClassView::MemberLockedNode },
            { _T("m_wndToolBar"), CClassView::MemberLockedNode, CClassView::MemberLockedNode },
            { _T("m_wndStatusBar"), CClassView::MemberLockedNode, CClassView::MemberLockedNode },
        { _T("Globals"), CClassView::FolderNode, CClassView::FolderNode },
            { _T("theFakeApp"), CClassView::MemberNode, CClassView::MemberNode },
    { _T(""), 0, 0 }
};

CClassView::ItemToInsert xray3[] = {
    { _T("CAdditionalDelay"), CClassView::TreeNode, CClassView::TreeNode },
        { _T("CAdditionalDelayMethod()"), CClassView::MethodNode, CClassView::MethodNode },
    { _T(""), 0, 0 }
};
```

I then exercises this message handler by spinning off two `concurrency` tasks in the `CMainFrame::OnCreate()` method which did a time delay and then updated the ClassView window tree contents.

```
concurrency::create_task([this]() { Sleep(5000);  this->SendMessageToClassView(WM_APP, 1, (LPARAM)xray2); }); 
concurrency::create_task([this]() { Sleep(10000);  this->SendMessageToClassView(WM_APP, 1, (LPARAM)xray3); });
```

Comment: That appears to be using the PPL. While still supported, it is recommended to switch to C++ coroutines, if your compiler supports them. There is information about the details in [this C++/WinRT issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/cppwinrt/issues/54). Regardless of which you choose, you need to be careful about object lifetimes. Capturing pointers/references in lambdas as well as passing pointers/references into C++ coroutines can fail at runtime in spectacular ways. Passing by value is usually safe. If you need to pass a pointer, consider using a weak pointer to determine existence at runtime.

Comment: @IInspectable thank you for your comment. I have updated my answer with an example using coroutines and `co_await`. The document whose link you provided had a link to a CppCon talk that had a source code example where suddenly the light came on about using `co_await`. What I found was that `winrt::init_apartment();` did not seem necessary with the new function. Can you point me to someplace that explains that? I will need to look further into weak pointers.